# How to solve this nonlinear difference equation $y_{t+1}-y_{t}+ty_{t+1}y_{t}=0$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I need help to solve the following difference equation:
$$y_{t+1}-y_{t}+ty_{t+1}y_{t}=0$$

I start by dividing with $y_{t+1}y_{t}$. Then I get:
$$y_{t}^{-1}-y_{t+1}^{-1}=-t$$
Then I assume $y_{t}=\frac{1}{m^{t}}$ and find general solution to corresponding homogeneous equation:
$$y_t=C_{1}\left ( 1 \right )^{t}+C_{2}t(1)^{t}\quad\Rightarrow\quad y_t=C_{1}+C_{2}t$$
Hoping that the solution is correct so far, I need help in finding a particular solution to nonhomogeneous equation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With $z_t=y_t^{-1}$ we get
$$
z_{t+1}-z_t=t.
$$
Summing up for $t=0,\ldots,n-1$ you will get the telescopic sum in LHS and an easy to calculate in RHS. It gives you $z_n$ and, thus, $y_n$.

P.S. Your homogeneous equation would be $z_{t+1}=z_t$, it has only constant solutions, where does the term $...+C_2t$ for $y_t$ come from?